# Tensorflow transfered learning for image classification gives same accuracy for each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, transfer-learning

I followed this tutorial ([article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/transfer-learning-using-inception-v3-for-image-classification-86700411251b) & [code](https://github.com/tejanirla/image_classification/blob/master/transfer_learning.ipynb)) and with provided data set it went well. But when I tried to use my own pictures in two categories it behaves strange and model is useless. Every single epoch gives me the same results:

```
Epoch 1/50
49/49 [==============================] - 63s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 1. 241s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/50
49/49 [==============================] - 62s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 2. 259s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/50
49/49 [==============================] - 61s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 3. 237s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/50
49/49 [==============================] - 62s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 4. 238s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/50
49/49 [==============================] - 62s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 5. 239s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/50
49/49 [==============================] - 61s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 6. 239s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/50
49/49 [==============================] - 61s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 7. 238s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/50
49/49 [==============================] - 62s 1s/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000
 8. 241s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

I didn't change any settings only data set.

There are some differences between mine and original dataset:
- I have less pictures for each object / folder. Instead of 1500 pictures I have just few hundreds for each object
- Original dataset was used only to recognize between cats and dogs, so input data are more diversified (each pic is another dog or cat). In my case for one target class each picture is the same object but from different angle, position etc.

My goal is to create a model, that would be able to recognize different products. I don't want to tell classify the object is a bottle of milk, I but want to train if it's milk product A, milk product B etc.. So in my case, each folder is filled with different products.

Where I made mistake? I can't understand, that same code behaves so different for another dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Not all NNs are valid for all data. Otherwise there would be only 1 NN.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there some way to figure out which NN would be more suitable for my data? (I mean except trying.. ) For example, on the same data I created much better model wit mobilenet, but expected Inception to be better..

Comment: Research, expertise, reading, learning math, mostly.